# Azure AD B2C with EasyAuth for Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, easy-auth

We are using Azure AD B2C with custom policies in a SPA in Kubernetes and have seen that EasyAuth can also be used in Kubernetes with Azure AD (https://github.com/Azure/EasyAuthForK8s). The page also says that "Azure AD B2C custom policies for complex identity flows" are included. Does this mean that I can include EasyAuth in Kubernetes and add it to my policies for login and registration or does Azure AD B2C handle this itself? If I can include it in my policies, are there any examples of this? I haven't found anything on this yet unfortunately.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Thanks @Steffen, the architecture shows EsayAuth validate with AAD B2C environment. Please setup custom policy in AAD B2C with this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started and let us know if you need more information and also update the proper value in this file - https://github.com/Azure/EasyAuthForK8s/blob/master/charts/msal-proxy/values.yaml

Comment: @Jit_MSFT Thank you very much. If I understand this correctly, I have to adjust the AzureASCallbackPath, AzureAdSignedOutCallbackPath, etc., among other things, do I understand this correctly, Or only the e.g. AZURE_TENANT_ID? We have already converted the policies according to the instructions.

Comment: Hey, I have also tried this before with the Custom Policy starterpack "SocialAndLocalAccounts", but unfortunately I didn't get it working. Do I need to customize something in these policies as well to use EasyAuth or is customizing the tenant variables in Kubernetes enough as Steffen asked? Sorry for the question, but I am new to the field with AZure AD B2C and Kubernetes.

Comment: Creating a new issue to clarify how to configure this: https://github.com/Azure/EasyAuthForK8s/issues/24